# How to find the height of two spheres contained in a known cylinder with the radius of both spheres being known?

Tags: geometry

I was working on a practice problem for a tournament and this one stumped everyone including our advisor. We know the answer to be $346\pi/3$ cm$^3$. From this we reversed the problem to find that the height of the top of the spheres must be $8$ cm however we were unable to determine how to find this.

[image: enter image description here][1]]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Let $\angle FKJ=\theta$ then,
$$IF+JK+KE=9\implies 2+5\cos\theta+3=9\implies \cos\theta=\frac45.$$
Then, $\sin\theta=\frac35$ and the height is, $$2+5\sin\theta+3=2+3+3=8.$$

Comment: Note: You could've also used Pythagoras with the known 3-4-5-triangle